# Jquery Dropdown dynamic Form Issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, drop-down-menu

Hi all I have the following dropdown:

```
<div id='drop'>
    <select name='option'>
        <option value="Opt1">Opt1</option>
        <option value="Opt2">Opt2</option>
        <option value="Opt3">Opt3</option>
    </select>
</div>

<div id = 'NewContent'>
   //I need different content here depending on selection
   <div id="form1" style="display:none">Content of Form1</div>
   <div id="form2"style="display:none">Content of Form2</div>
   <div id="form3"style="display:none">Content of Form3</div>
</div>
```

I then have the following Javascript:

```
$('select[name="option"]').change(function() {
    $('#NewContent').find('*').hide();
   $('#'+$(this).val()).show();
});
```

this will work and display: Content of Form 1, 2 etc. when the user changes the dropdown.

However - the issue is, If I were to simply change one of the divs to include another - nothing displays on the screen, EG.:

```
  <div id = 'NewContent'>
       //I need different content here depending on selection
       <div id="form1" style="display:none"><div>Content of Form1</div></div> //this won't show  anything 
       <div id="form2"style="display:none">Content of Form2</div>
       <div id="form3"style="display:none">Content of Form3</div>
    </div>
```

is there a way to get around this issue??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is your html..
In your html, whenever there's any change in dropdown "**$(this).val()**" will always return "Opt1", "Opt2" or "Opt3" and in your html doesn't have any id's with "Opt1", "Opt2" or "Opt3".
So, try this:

```
<div id='drop'>
    <select name='option'>
        <option value="form1">Opt1</option>
        <option value="form2">Opt2</option>
        <option value="form3">Opt3</option>
   </select>
</div>

<div id = 'NewContent'>
//I need different content here depending on selection
   <div id="form1" style="display:none">Content of Form1</div>
   <div id="form2"style="display:none" >Content of Form2</div>
   <div id="form3"style="display:none">Content of Form3</div>
</div>

$('select[name="option"]').change(function() {
   $('#NewContent').children().hide();
   $('#'+$(this).val()).show();
});
```

Comment: this works however when the page is first loaded all of the Divs appear on the screen at the same time

Comment: How's that possible, have you added "style='display: none'" in all divs ?

Comment: Ok, check this plnkr, if this is what you want..[Plnkr Link](http://plnkr.co/edit/3dmVFW7NC52JHq8qnJae?p=preview)

Answer (score 1):

Only hide the children, not all descendants (`*`). By using `find('*').hide()` you are hiding all descendants and so when you come to show one of the divs, it will be shown but its children remain hidden.

```
$('#NewContent').children().hide();
```

Comment: Legend - thankyou very much I have been stuck on this for an age!